# Browser Tab Close Event for javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added a div which contains some survey questions which is initially hidden. Once the user closes the window or navigate away from the page, I need to popup the survey div to get the confirmation. I know there is a browser default confirm box method by using `onbeforeunload` event. But I need to popup the div rather than the browser default confirm box. Is there any way to do this? (or is there any way to interrupt the close event without even clicks on the "Stay on page" button found in the browser default confirm box?)

Comment: anyway??>..rather using confirm use your own custom callback which returns a boolean in the end...

Comment: Thanks @CodeJack Can you please give me a code sample to get clear your answer

Comment: Thankfully, no you cannot do what you are asking.  All you have is the option of the confirmation box.  As annoying as that window can be (when it's used for the wrong reason), it's nowhere near as annoying as what you suggest.  I literally would never go back to a site that did what you are suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE** : it seems we cannot do the action you are asking. There are some solutions to cover this in IE but overall its not possible. Ignore all the previous code.

Comment: yep..jsbin doesnt allow to bind for that

Comment: Actually, that was wrong.  It *does* show (which means that jsbin does allow binding that event), but you only see it for a fraction of a second before the tab closes, which is correct.  You cannot do what the OP is asking.

Comment: This works. But the problem is the tab closed before made any action to the popup. Can we avoid this?? I mean can we halt the close event?